# Best wording/etc when I know the answer to the question I am asking?

Tags: discussion

I have what I think is a pretty cool question +answer. What is the best way to encourage discussion (possibly find alternative solutions)?

How long to leave the question before answering? I think this is better place to talk about this before trying because I am sure there will be an optimal method.

My current thought is to broaden the topic so it can apply to more situations than my own, leave it for an amount of time (I'm hoping an active member can give a clue), and then post the solution (this case example bash script and python).

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely [answer your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12513/181389) if you have a good answer!  This is a great way of sharing knowledge when you've worked your way through a problem you think others may encounter.  If someone else has a better answer, they can leave it and it can be upvoted.  If you think it's more of an ongoing discussion, you can make your answer a community wiki so many users will be able to contribute to the same answer.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure there is an optimal procedure, but, I would suggest posting your specific question and waiting at least a couple of days before answering it yourself (assuming no one has provided a better answer already). My reasoning is this: unanswered questions and questions without an accepted answer are likely to receive more views and elicit more third party responses. Broadening your question may sound like a good idea, but ask yourself this "Do I come to the site looking for a general question and answer or am I trying to solve a specific problem?" A more specific question will likely rank higher in search results (either here or from Google etc.) and again draw more views and potential answers.

Comment: Would it then be beneficial to adjust my question so it represents what more people may be searching for now?

Comment: I would say no. How do you know what people are going to search for? That turns the whole group thinking community idea behind stackexchange on its head.